# Relative Imports in Typescript and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to build a node app using typescript. The plan is to deploy the `build` folder independently (i.e. it has it's own `node_modules`). Here is an MWE of my folder structure:

```
root
|-node_modules
|-src
|  |-index.ts
|  |-other.ts
|-build
|  |-node_modules
|  |-index.js
|  |-other.js
|  |-package.json
|  |-package-lock.json
|-package.json
|-package-lock.json
|-tsconfig.json
```

The `index.ts` and `other.ts` files contains the following:

```
//index.ts                               ||   //other.ts
import { HelloWorld } from "./other";    ||   export function HelloWorld() {
                                         ||     console.log("Hello World!");
HelloWorld();                            ||   }
```

The `package.json` file looks like (the real one contains `devDependencies` and `dependencies` as well):

```
{
  "name":"MyApp",
  "version":"0.1.0",
  "type":"module"
}
```

The `tsconfig.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl":"src",
    "rootDir":"./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true
    },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I am building my `build` folder by first copying the `package.json` file into `build`, running `npm install --prefix ./build --omit=dev` to get a production ready `node_modules` folder, then running `npx tsc` to build the `.js` files.

When I try and run `node build/index.js`, I get the following error:

```
ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND:
Cannot find module 'C:Users\MichaelBarrowman\TestRepo\build\other' imported from 'C:Users\MichaelBarrowman\TestRepo\build\index.js'
```

I tried to change the `moduleResolution` to `node16` in the `tsconfig.json` file, and I get:

```
Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in EcmaScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'.
```

I was under the impression that using the Node16 resolution algorithm, the `"./other"` in the `import` statement in `index.ts`/`index.js` would be resolved to `"./other.js"` automatically.

I am running locally on `Node v18.12.1` (but these errors persist on a server using `Node20`) with `typescript` version `8.19.2`

Comment: "I am building my build folder by first copying the package.json file into build [...]" why? `tsc` already copies the compiled source to the dir you tell it to, and the top level `node_modules` will resolve just fine from any subdirectory; you don't need to copy your package.json and then run `npm install` inside `build`. Where is the npm script that runs the typescript compile pass?

Comment: I am creating a separate `node_modules` directory in the `build` folder because this folder is going to be deployed on it's own. The workflow is going to be under CI/CD pipeline and the `build` folder will be a separate branch.

Comment: Can't say that makes a lot of sense, you may want to read up on how TS-based projects are typically deployed a bit (you're basically doing something _very_ unusual probably for reasons that don't actually require you to do this at all)

Comment: I appreciate the concern for my workflow, but your response doesn't really address the question I was asking.

Comment: That's why it was a comment, not an answer post. Not all problems are best solved by posting an answer, some require reexamining the setup that _allows_ the problem to even exists. (And when you do something very unusual, you typically want to explain why in your post, so that folks who are familiar with the thing you're asking about and the methodologies around that can understand why you're doing something so different from convention, because otherwise the first step is to stop doing things differently and follow the normal approach and see if that fixes things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify your package / project with `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, your relative file imports [MUST contain the file extension](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html#type-in-packagejson-and-new-extensions).

> relative import paths need full extensions (e.g we have to write `import "./foo.js"` instead of `import "./foo"`)

Furthermore, even if you initially write your file in TypeScript (with `.ts` file extension), you should directly use the *final* file extension (so `.js`); `tsc` knows how to handle it.

> it will have to be rewritten to use the extension of the *output* of `foo.ts` - so `bar.ts` will instead have to import from `./foo.js`.

So simply make sure to add file extensions to your imports:

```
import { HelloWorld } from "./other.js"; // Notice the file extension
```

Comment: So the only way to combat this is to specifically import `.js` files? But that seems really bizarre, especially since when I am writing the code, I am actually trying to import a `.ts` file (at that point in the workflow). In theory, I shouldn't really even have to think about the `.js` transpiled files

Comment: Or you can remove the `"type": "module"`

Comment: "_I shouldn't really even have to think about the .js transpiled files_": yes and no... I agree that DX is better without extension. But unfortunately,  `tsc` by design does not touch the import path. So if you tell Node you will write the extension (with type module), `tsc` will _not_ do it automatically for you.